# get the values in public

Tags: c#

```
class Product
{
    private string Produuct;
    private decimal Price;
    private decimal Vat;
    private bool Food;
    private int Count;

    private const decimal foodVATRate = 0.12m, otherVATRate = 0.25m;
    private decimal Finalprice;
    private decimal Rate;

    public void Start()
    {
    }

    private void Readinput();
    {
        Console.Write("\n\nWhat is the product you want:  ");
        Produuct = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Unit price:  ");
        decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Price);
        Console.Write("Food item y/n:  ");
        char answer = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if ((answer == 'y') || (answer == 'Y'))
        {
            Food = true;
            Vat = foodVATRate;
        }
        else
        {
            Food = false;
            Vat = otherVATRate;
        }
        Console.Write("Count:  ");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Count);
    }

    private void CalculateValues();
    {
        Finalprice = Price * Count;
        Rate = Finalprice * Vat;
    }

    private void Printrecept();
    {
        Console.Write("\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        Console.Write("\n\nThe product you want is: " + Produuct);
        Console.Write("\nThe price: " + Price);
        Console.Write("\nFood item: " + Food);
        Console.Write("\nCount: " + Count);
        Console.Write("\n\nTotal price: " + Finalprice);
        Console.Write("\nVAT at " + Rate);
        Console.Write("\n\n+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
     }
}
```

I need help with how i'm going to call the values from `ReadInput()`, `CalculateValues()`, `Printrecept()` in `Start()` so I can see it on the screen.

I know that you need to have a return and get but I really dont know how to do it here.

Comment: Homework? If so tag it as such.

Comment: Please clean up the code formatting. If the `using` and `namespace` statements are not relevant you can and should remove them.

Comment: I think you need to read this; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct. Then this is what you need:

```
void Main()
{
    Product p=new Product();
    p.Start();
}
```

And inside the class:

```
public void Start()
{
    Readinput();
    CalculateValues();
    Printrecept();
}
```